# Cordova Android app and user permissions

Tags: android, cordova, permissions, gps

I have an Android Cordova app and I'm using GPS, check the network state, read/write on the Documents folder and taking camera pictures. Here my permissions on the manifest XML file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

The manifest file is auto generated by the Cordova framework. For some reason I don't see camera permissions. Permissions are not asked at installation time anymore (that's since Android 6) but instead they should be asked before usage.
I correctly get the GPS access permission popup but not the read/write Documents folder permission. I also never get the camera permission albeit I'm able to use it without ever being asked for permission. Same story for the Network status permissions (never being asked).

I find Android permissions scheme extremely confusing, under application manager my app has got Location and Storage as expected, Camera and Network status are missing though.

To recap, inside the app, on the actual code, I'm using at least once those devices

- GPS fine grained
- GPS coarse (probably the Wifi SSID triangulation trick)
- Write on Documents
- Read on Documents
- Read network status (Offline / Wifi / 3G etc..)
- Take picture from the camera

Cordova framework wrote this manifest file:

- android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
- android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
- android.hardware.location.gps (why is it not a .permission?)
- android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
- android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

On application manager I get those options:

- Location
- Storage

So basically I get three different sets of permissions :-(

Comment: I don't get what is your problem. What is wrong with having three different sets of permission. You can use those permission that you need and if they are critical permission, you need to check of they are granted to you and if not ask user to grant the permission.

Comment: My problem is that I see an inconsistent listing of permissions on three different places: my code, manifest file, application settings UI.... Ideally if on my code I make use of the camera then I should see a camera permission on the manifest file and a camera permission on the application settings UI.. same story for any other device (GPS, camera, network, filesystem etc..)

Comment: In your code (in your config.xml file) you declare the permission you want and when you build your app, all manifest files are merged, so if you use some libraries and third party tools, their required permissions are merged into a single manifest file along with your permissions. And about different presentation on application settings UI and in your manifest: thats because in UI they need to be self-explanatory for all users which most of them are not programmers, it doesn't mean that they are different from what you added in your manifest, just the presentation is different.

Comment: Ok that's fine but then why I don't see a "Camera" permission on the UI? I'm using the camera on my app... On the UI I only see "Location" and "Storage"

Comment: You don't have `camera` permission in the manifest permissions you posted. If it is your `merged manifest` I don't understand how you can access camera. Maybe because your phone is rooted (just a guess)? Although this does not sound right for a rooted device too.

Comment: it's not rooted. I access the camera via a cordova plugin https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera

Comment: Are you sure `camera` permission is not available in your `merged-manifest`? Can you possibly send the `apk` file for me to check it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this in the [this `cordova` plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera) that you mentioned in comments.

[image]

So somehow this `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA/>` have to be in your code so as this plugin can use it.

Maybe you didn't check the right program to see its permissions, or if the camera permission is not shown in application permissions on device, you can't be able to use camera in this application. Please do a check again because I really want to know what is the situation.